# Not mapped colum in @OneToOne JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

I have two Entities (foo and bar) and when I mapped from foo all works ok:

In Foo

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private Bar bar;
```

And in Bar

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "bar", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private Foo foo;
```

When I save a foo, as I expected, the id of the included bar is stored in the new foo entry in the bar_id colum.

But if I do it in reverse, in Foo

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "foo", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private Bar bar;
```

And in Bar

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private Foo foo;
```

I expect, when I save a Foo, the id of the foo where the bar is included will store in the foo_id colum in the new entry in the bar table, but in this case is always null, and then don't works when I get it.

PS: I know is enough with works in the first case, but for some constrains I prefeer the second one, and on the other hand, I want to know why this is happens for prevent in future

As @SternK recomend I follow the [@OneToOne bidrectional example](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-one-bidirectional) from the documentation adding to Foo Class the methods

```
    public void addBar(Bar bar) {
    bar.setFoo( this );
    this.bar = bar;
}

public void removeBar() {
    if ( bar != null ) {
        bar.setFoo( null );
        this.bar = null;
    }
}
```

But still the  foo_id colum is null and when I do a get of the foo I have

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "foo1",
    "bar": null
}
```

Comment: I don't know if I will have to see but I notice the example class are static and when I try to create mine as static, Eclipse say:  Illegal modifier for the class Phone; only public, abstract & final are permitted

Comment: I create a minimum app to reproduce the problem and ask specificaly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64733460/simple-bidirectional-onetoone-store-null

Answer (score 0):

If you use bidirectional association (usage `mappedBy` property indicates about it) then as it stated in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional-example) you should make both sides in-sync:

> Whenever a bidirectional association is formed, the application developer must make sure both sides are in-sync at all times.

This means you should have the following methods in `Foo`:

```java
@Entity
public class Foo
{

   public void addBar(Bar bar)
   {
      this.bar = bar;
      bar.setFoo(this);
   }

   public void removeBar() {
      if (bar != null ) {
         bar.setFoo( null );
         this.bar = null;
      }
   }
}
```